# Ubuntu 18.04 display UNCLAIMED

Tags: drivers, 18.04, display, brightness

My lenovo laptop E590 has been working fine since December 2018, with Ubuntu 18.04.

But suddenly, since yesterday I am facing an issue. If I switch on the laptop it gets stuck at "starting Gnome Display Manager". Then, I switch off and on restart enter the recovery mode. I enable networking and the do a normal resume; I am able to do login in normal graphical mode ( gdm3). I have already done this quite a few times. So, this is obviously not ideal. Also, the brightness keys are not working. I tried switching to `lightdm` but the same issue occurs. Please help. Thanks.

The output of `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1000000-a1ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550/550X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a01fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2300000-a233ffff memory:a2340000-a235ffff
```

The output of `ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/0000:05:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d00002526sv00008086sd00000014bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated - `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` -, reboot and check again.

Comment: Wow @ChanganAuto. It worked! Thanks for taking time to comment.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - please write the comment as an answer and then sunchi please mark it as accepted if it really helped. And thank You both: for posting the question and the answer.